# d3js timeline -- on scrub day generate a clean granular view for date and time

Tags: d3.js

I am building a timeline chart - that will change its date scale at the top when the brush becomes small to the scope of 1 day -- but when it hits this mode -- the labels overlap and it looks messy until you get to a 12 hour spread.

What is the best way of cleaning this functionality up so it doesn't overlap. I thought about having 1 line that shows date -- and another line under it that shows the hours at that level.

https://jsfiddle.net/aLh9d51t/

[image]

```
    var tFormat = '%Y-%m';
    var tTick = 'timeMonth';
    if (days < 40) {
        tFormat = '%Y-%m-%d';
        tTick = 'timeWeek';
    }

    if (days <= 7) {
        tFormat = '%Y-%m-%d';
        tTick = 'timeDay';
    }

    if (days <= 1) {
        tFormat = '%Y-%m-%d %H%p';
        tTick = 'timeHour';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can hide redundant parts of date when possible: show years, months, days only if there are more than one visible. So you definitely do not need years and months when you show hours and minutes.
Just look how default d3 axis handles this (e.g. https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1166403).

Second, considering your chart has fixed width, you can fine-tune different formats for different zoom levels (you already do this in your code snippet).

Take a look at this example: http://bl.ocks.org/oluckyman/6199145
It has similar logic as in your code snippet: 
https://gist.github.com/oluckyman/6199145#file-axisdaysview-js-L33-L58
But the decision which format to choose depends on chart width:
https://gist.github.com/oluckyman/6199145#file-axisdaysview-js-L72-L75

And third, if you restricted to long labels for some reason, you can [rotate them](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/3c040800ff6457717cca586ae9547dbf) to 30°-45°

Also this could be useful: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4149176

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rwv360ga/  -- there is a customformat here